# Empty UIPickerView in second view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I have problem with a picker view that appears empty when I make it in second view controller.(image1).

When I make it in the first view controller that work fine.
[two view controller and pickerview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sffe.png)

**code:**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate {
    var civilite = ["Madame","Monsieur","Mademoiselle"]

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return civilite.count
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String!{
        return civilite[row]
    }

}
```

Xcode 6.4

Comment: Have you made the 2nd view controller the delegate for the picker view?

Comment: yes i made the delegate for the picker view
http://i.stack.imgur.com/ONGqp.png

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

I add new file "Cocoa touch class" (Formulaire.swift) 
 I change the custom class of the second view controller to be "Formulaire" [Custom class][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4Nip.png 
I deplace the code in this file and is work fine.
Thanks